# convert css string to a format acceptable by node request file upload

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I have a node backend where I am doing a file upload. the following works for me:

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'xxx',
    formData: {
        file: {
            value: fs.createReadStream('new1.css'),
            options: {
                contentType: 'text/css'
            }
        }
    }
};

let resp: any  = await request(options);
```

However, in my case, I will not be having a file I could read as above. I will be just having a css string. How can I convert my css string to a format similar to fs.createReadStream('new1.css')

I tried approach from the answer below, but it does not work for me. I tried printed the JSON.stringify(fs.createReadStream('new1.css')) and output is:

```
{"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":65536,
"buffer":{"head":null,"tail":null,"length":0},
"length":0,
"pipes":null,
"pipesCount":0,
"flowing":null,
"ended":false,
"endEmitted":false,
"reading":false,
"sync":true,
"needReadable":false,
"emittedReadable":false,
"readableListening":false,
"resumeScheduled":false,
"defaultEncoding":"utf8",
"ranOut":false,
"awaitDrain":0,
"readingMore":false,
"decoder":null,
"encoding":null},
"readable":true,
"domain":null,
"_events":{},
"_eventsCount":1,
"path":"new2.css",
"fd":null,
"flags":"r",
"mode":438,
"autoClose":true,
"bytesRead":0}
```

I also printed the JSON.stringify(css) and the output is:

```
{"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,
"buffer":{"head":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[98,111,100,121,32,123,125]},"next":null},
    "tail":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[98,111,100,121,32,123,125]},"next":null},"length":1},
"length":7,
"pipes":null,
"pipesCount":0,
"flowing":null,
"ended":true,
"endEmitted":false,
"reading":false,
"sync":true,
"needReadable":false,
"emittedReadable":true,
"readableListening":false,
"resumeScheduled":false,
"defaultEncoding":"utf8",
"ranOut":false,
"awaitDrain":0,
"readingMore":true,
"decoder":null,
"encoding":null},
"readable":true,
"domain":null,
"_events":{},
"_eventsCount":0}
```

I am not sure which difference is causing the issue. And how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use Node.js [Stream API](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), create a `Readable` stream and push your css

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable
var css = new Readable
css.push('body {}')    // your css string
css.push(null)      // indicates the end of the stream


var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'xxx',
    formData: {
        file: {
            value: css,
            options: {
                contentType: 'text/css'
            }
        }
    }
};
let resp: any  = await request(options)
```

Comment: Farnabaz, I tried this approach but I just get a 500 error from the server. Everything works fine with fs.createReadStream('new1.css') though.

Comment: @user1892775 could you paste your server log here?

Comment: Farnabaz, I dont have access to that server, atleast not right now. All I can see is the 500 error that I receive. Is there some other way to debug this meanwhile?